# A modem router with isolated wifis

Tags: wifi, router

I'm looking for a router, which has a built-in modem one that can have two wifi networks completely isolated from one another.

I'm hoping to isolate various appliances, e.g. a refrigerator connected to wifi X
should have no way to interact with my personal laptop connected to wifi Y over LAN.

The other major requirement, (which I'm pretty sure I'm not describing well enough) is
that the router support optic fibers as the one provided by my ISP.

Let me know if there is more info I can share.

Comment: What do you mean by "connected to wifi Y over LAN"?

That there are two routers connected with a LAN cable?

Or simply that there is a (wifi) LAN X and a (wifi) LAN Y?

Comment: It seems like you have requirements for a system that is better off being set up with a dedicated modem and two routers. Also, keep in mind that two routers plugged into a modem may require two IP addresses from your ISP if the modem doesn't have NAT or its own router functionality.

Comment: What's your budget? The proper way to do this is with VLANs rather than two different Wi-Fi networks, but I want to make sure it's within budge for you.

Comment: I think a ~100$ - But do share your knowledge